# *ngFor Looping over array

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I have the following array:

```
{
    "body": [{
        "coursename": "introto1",
        "course-lesson-name": "Welcome to One! "
    }, {
        "coursename": "introto2",
        "course-lesson-name": "What is One?"
    }, {
        "coursename": "introto2",
        "course-lesson-name": "What Can We do with One?"
    }]
}
```

and I am using the following *ngFor to iterate over it:

```
<div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let product of products | keyvalue">
        <a>{{ products.body[0]['coursename'] }}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, the above is locked down to the first element only, ***what do I use instead of the element number (body[0]) to serve as as the iterable?***

here is my component if its needed:

```
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {

  products;

  constructor(private dataService: MenuserviceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.dataService.sendGetRequest().subscribe((data: any[])=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.products = data;
    })  
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `product` variable instead of `products.body[0]` and don't use the `keyvalue` pipe:

```
<div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let product of products?.body">
        <a>{{ product['coursename'] }}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You would use `keyvalue` when you are iterating over an object's properties, not an array: [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

Check also this [page](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) about how to use `NgForOf`.

Comment: Ive tried that already and got this error:  NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. Thats why I was using keyValue.

Comment: try using async pipe instead of keyvalue

Comment: `async` is to be used with Observables, but the `products` variable is not an Observable.

Comment: @MondKin I guess the `products` isn't defined at the moment you try to iterate, so I believe that using the safe navigation operator (`?`) should solve the issue with your answer: `*ngFor="let product of products?.body"`. Or, better yet, @DataGuy, I suggest you to use `async` pipe :)

Comment: @MondKin products is defined in the component as an empty to hold the response.

Comment: @MondKin - thanks! the ? made it happen - havent seen that all day long in any of my searches. Now, on to making each iteration a link! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Error is because *NgFor works only for **[Arrays]** and **[Objects with keyValue]**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v812v6

Check this out

```
<div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let product of response.body">
        <a>{{ product['coursename'] }}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  response = {
    "body": [{
        "coursename": "introto1",
        "course-lesson-name": "Welcome to One! "
    }, {
        "coursename": "introto2",
        "course-lesson-name": "What is One?"
    }, {
        "coursename": "introto2",
        "course-lesson-name": "What Can We do with One?"
    }]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need here keyvalue, body is an array of objects and **ngFor** is mostly for iterating thought arrays

```
<div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let product of products?.body">
   <a>{{ product.coursename }}</a>
</div>
```

your subscription function parameter type is incorrect - any[], it is not an array, it is {body: any[]}, so I would say change it to any at least, or as it is TypeScript maybe create an interface that corresponds the response structure.